# Mongoose/MongoDB suddenly not working (Topology error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Node/Express backend that I created almost 2 years ago and it has worked without fail until now. I loaded up my dev server for the first time in around a month and my backend is now showing this error:

> MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32)
> at C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:348:10
> at promiseOrCallback (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1152:10)
> at Mongoose.connect (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:347:20)
> at accountDBHandler.build (C:\taxi-booker\backend\DBHandlers\accountsDB.js:16:20)
> at C:\taxi-booker\backend\serverClass.js:640:27
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at C:\taxi-booker\backend\serverClass.js:71:6
> at C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
> at getSecret (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
> at checkToken (C:\taxi-booker\backend\serverClass.js:66:8)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\taxi-booker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> {   reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Single',
> setName: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> maxElectionId: null,
> servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> compatibilityError: null,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> commonWireVersion: null   } }

This error was caught here:

```
async build() {
        try {
            if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
                await mongoose.connect(
                    this.connectionURL,
                    {
                        useNewUrlParser: true,
                        useUnifiedTopology: true
                    },
                    err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            console.log("connection error");
                        } else {
                            console.log(chalk.greenBright("Successful connection to database"));
                        }
                    }
                );
                mongoose.pluralize(null);
            }
            this.accounts = mongoose.model("Accounts", accountSchema);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
```

I am using the following versions:

- Node 17.3
- MongoDB 4.2.6
- Mongoose 5.12.3
- Windows 10

I can also connect to my DB perfectly fine through Compass.

Comment: Anything relevant in mongo logs?

Comment: Nothing at all in mongo logs

Comment: A long shot, but `ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 ` suggests  localhost is resolved to its IPv6 address. Try to change connection settings to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you